# Hotel rooms reservation modul for EE 3

Tags: ee3

I would like to know if there is a quality module for booking hotel rooms for EE 3?

I have found this for EE 2, but I need it on EE3?

Comment: Are you find any addon for this need?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  But i wish. A booking addon would be amazing.. if you find one let me know